# Building libnoise for mingw

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, g++

I am currently trying to install the libnoise library for mingw via a .a file. I've tried several things but I am not really that much experienced with makefiles.
I've ran through the included makefile and at the end it throws a "Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"

The .lib file does indeed work, but is there any way to compile my program through a .a library? I would be glad if someone would show me how to actually make a .a myself since I have no experience and I can't find where to start.

Comment: Could you show your makefile please?

Comment: It is the default makefile that is included in the source download noise/Makefile.
see http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/downloads/index.html - Full Source

Comment: You have to link it. and you need to specify that your application is a console program: the linker needs to get the following parameter in your makefile **/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE** . I guess it is a good idea to post the makefile to build your application

Comment: You might have not understand me. I want to build the library "libnoise" to also work on other compilers than mingw and vc++. So I need to build a .a file. The libnoise library comes with a .lib, not a .a file, so you have to build it yourself. I have mentioned that the makefile is the makefile of the source from libnoise. I though need help builing the library as .a

Comment: Which compilers and platforms do you have in mind? The lib supports already an automake build environment. And .lib is the extension for libraries under windows, .a for unix ( mingw is providing a posix / unix system for windows, so .a will work there as well ). You could use cmake to generate an easier integration for other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly what to do on libnoise while it came to my mind today.

1) install libnoise on github from https://github.com/eXpl0it3r/libnoise

2) run cmake with entries CMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=gcc CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=g++ (easiest to do with cmake GUI)

it is recommended to generate into another folder, perhaps create a new one.I created one in a new one called libnoise-master/lib

3) inside that, run

```
make
```

if make doesn't work you might a) not have set up the PATH variable or b) inside your MinGW/bin you can't find make, but mingw32-make. Either rename it to make or use mingw32-make instead of make

after all of that you will generate a .a file if you havent chosen a shared library on step 2 or a .dll if you did